# When is it better to use ssh-keyscan instead of ssh to manage known_hosts?

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, known-hosts

When is executed

```
ssh -i id_rsa_something remoteuser@192.168.1.2
```

appears:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.1.2 (192.168.1.2)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:ABCABC [fixed/changed].
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

If I write yes I can get access to the remote server through SSH. So until here the SSH configuration for remote connections works as expected. Furthermore in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file, in the *client*, was added:

```
192.168.1.2 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNo...
```

So the client knows through the `.ssh/known_hosts` file that has a trusted server and in the server side through the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file exists a copy of the public key of the client. Until here the security connection can be established in peace between the client and server.

I thought that it is the unique logical approach to establish a connection between the client and server (lets call this the *first approach*). I mean, generate keys, copy the public key to the server and finally do the connection as the first command shared (even with SSH Agent running or not).

Now, I did a research in StackExchange branches about how to delete a fingerprint in the client side, it through the `ssh-agent -R hostname` command that affects the `.ssh/known_hosts` file and generates the `known_hosts.old` file and works, but in the solutions posted appears how extra information many times the `ssh-keyscan` to add the fingerprint of the host in the `.ssh/known_hosts` file - I did a research about that, and the tutorials only teach how to use - I couldn't find a solid reason about when would be mandatory use `ssh-keyscan` over the *first approach*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results of adding the host key to the `known_hosts` explicitly using `ssh-keyscan` or by connecting using `ssh` are technically the same.

Though `ssh-keyscan` does not really give you a chance to verify that the host key is valid. So you would have to ex-post check the contents of the `known_hosts`, eventually removing the key if it turns out that it is key of a malicious server. Also `known_hosts` contains a full key, which you can hardly verify. On the contrary the `ssh` shows you a fingerprint of the host key, which is easier to verify.